# Strange input field indent in Safari

Tags: html, css, input, safari, indentation

This code:

```
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor=red>
            <input type='text' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Gives this output in Safari and all other browsers:
[image]

The question is how to remove the indent that is highlighted with background color.
Problem occurs in Safari only, CSS margin/padding/border does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s probably some [margin](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin) on that `input` element. Try to remove it, e.g.:

```
<input type='text' style="margin:0" />
```